# To_date function in Vertica format?

Tags: database, date-formatting, vertica, to-date

How can I get Vertica function `to_date('','format')` do output like this:

```
DDMonYYYY - 01/ABR/2012
```

and not like it does (`01-04-2012`)?!

```
dbadmin=> select now();
              now
--------------------------------
 19/09/2012 11:03:48.284339 BRT
(1 row)

dbadmin=> show datestyle;
   name    | setting
-----------+----------
 datestyle | SQL, DMY
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'DD/MON/YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

to_date() takes a string and converts it into a date object. The output you see returned is not formatted to the specified format. It is just an acknowledgement that the date object got created.